# How can I restrain acess for my profile view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I did a view to access personal information. To do this, there is a pk in the URL. However, this is problematic because they can access other user info just by changing the value of the pk. I read the doc and I didn't find anything related to that.
How can I prevent this problem?

```
path('profil/<int:pk>', views.ProfilView.as_view(), name="profil")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no reason for the PK to be in the URL (i.e. you don't want to use the same view to view others' information), you can make your `ProfilView` look something like this, assuming it derives from `DetailView`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
# ...

class ProfilView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView): 
    model = User  # or whatever it happens to be

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user  # Always return the current user
```

and simply

```py
path('profil/', views.ProfilView.as_view(), name="profil")
```

in your URL configuration.

Comment: It's often useful to keep a distinction between the user who is logged in, and the person who's data is being viewed. E.g. customer-level admins should have access to see some user's profile pages, but maybe not all; and your customer-support personnel will find it useful to see the page the way your end-user sees it. By using `request.user` for both the logged in user and to fetch the user-data to view you're making those use-cases much more difficult.

Comment: "your customer-support personnel will find it useful to see the page the way your end-user sees it" – you'd have to build that into every single view, which is not very DRY. I'd use an impersonation framework like https://pypi.org/project/django-impersonate/ for that instead.

Comment: As long as you look up the user you're viewing (ie. not use `request.user` to find view-data), and implement a `can_request_user_view(user)` function there is very little work to be done. There is no repeating yourself (`person.fist_name` vs. `request.user.first_name` is not repeating yourself, you're simple starting at a user you've fetched e.g. by `pk`).  `django-impersonate` is probably a great project, but it doesn't solve this problem -- you still need access control, at least in the EU, where only the user themself (`request.user == person`) can view certain data.

Answer (score 0):

Require the user to be logged in, and display a 401 Unauthorized error if it's not their own profile id.

It might be useful have a `profil/me` url that always shows the user's own profile.

Comment: The user is logged via the django-provided LoginView. Can you give me more details about your implementation

Comment: At the top of `ProfilView()`, if the requested pk does not match the user's pk, redirect to a 401 page.